# NSManagedObject - How to get the type of the property

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios

I am trying to parse a json string straight into a managed object.
The json string contains all strings, but my Entity has Date objects.

if this is my json string

```
{
"name":"John",
"dob": "12/12/2008",
etc...
}
```

and here's my entity Person:

```
name : NSString
dob: Date
etc...
```

I want to parse that json straight through by looping through the keys of the Json dict, and setting the values to the matching keys of my entity:

```
Person *aPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSArray *keys = [jsonDict allKeys];

for (NSString *key in keys) {

 [aPerson setValue:[jsonDict valueForKey:key] forKey:key];

}
```

This only works if all my entity's properties are NSStrings.

How can I get the type/class of my entity's property to be able to set the various types?

eg.
if key = @"dob"
how can I get the type/class of aPerson.dob?

so my code will look something like:

```
Person *aPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSArray *keys = [jsonDict allKeys];

for (NSString *key in keys) {
    if([[aPerson objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]])
    {
       // Create an NSDate object
    }else{
       [aPerson setValue:[jsonDict valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
    }
}
```

thanks

**UPDATE:**

Ok I tried using the isKindOfClass and here's the result was:

```
// for key = @"name" 
// aPerson.name is NSString
[[aPerson valueForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] => TRUE
[[aPerson valueForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSObject class]] => TRUE

// for key = @"age"
// aPerson.age is NSNumber
[[aPerson valueForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] => TRUE
[[aPerson valueForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSObject class]] => TRUE

// for key = @"dob"
// aPerson.dob is NSDate
[[aPerson valueForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]] => FALSE
[[aPerson valueForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSObject class]] => FALSE
```

how is that? 
@dynamic dob and NSDate, is notOfClass NSDate!

please tell me what I am missing!

Comment: Alternatively to my answer below, you can run the above code with a if ([key isEqualToString:"dob"]) { // Create NSDate object... }

Comment: Thanks Rog, but I was hoping to make the parsing more dynamic, only picking up the type of the entity's property without having to know the name of the key ie. "dob"

Comment: Yup all fair points. This is untested by what about using `if ([[movie valueForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]])`

Comment: I tried that, but for some reason my NSDate property is not being recognized as kindOfClass NSDate! as posted in the update. thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the dob being returned as? NSNull or something else?

Comment: it's just logging (null). isKindOfClass:[NSNull class] is returning false. Trying to compare the difference between properties, after they initial insert, they all seem to have default values, except "dob" it's just (null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to Rog, for sending me in the right direction, I ended up overriding my setter as below:

```
-(void)setDob:(id)value
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"dob"];
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        [self setPrimitiveValue:[DateFormatter dateFromString:value] forKey:@"dob"];
    }else{
        [self setPrimitiveValue:value forKey:@"dob"];
    }
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"dob"];
}
```

and all works great now, instead of a 1000 lines of code parsing, it's all done in 3!
nice one!

Comment: Nice solution, clean & tidy. Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 3):

I know, this is a late answer, but as I was search today for a good solution...
This is what I'm using now:

```
NSEntityDescription * myEntity = [object entity];
NSDictionary * attributes = [myEntity attributesByName];
if ([[[attributes objectForKey:key] attributeValueClassName] isEqualToString:@"NSDate"]) {
    // this type is NSDate
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can either convert your JSON string to NSDate and then assign it to your NSManagedObject, or you can create a custom setter in your Person class that takes an NSString and returns NSDate. Here's an example:

```
- (NSDate*)convertStringToDate:(NSString*)dateString {  
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
    // if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMMM yyyy"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [dateFormatter release];
    return dateFromString;
}
```

Comment: thanks Rog, but I still need to know when I should convert the string to date. I need to know the type of xx in person.xx, to create their objects dynamically. eg. person.dob, person.loginDate etc... if i can tell that they are both NSDate properties, I can then create an NSDate out of that json string.

Comment: I also thought of overriding the setter to take an NSString to create the NSDate but then I will always be bound to using strings each time I want to set the "dob" in my app.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can pass (id) instead of an NSString and then make the conditional assessment with `isKindOfClass` within your setter.

Comment: tried that, the problem is that it creates an infinite loop, as i need to set the dob by it's setter, self.dob, being a dynamic property.

Comment: All good, I was able to implement the setter for the dynamic property and it works fine now. thanks for your help. I have posted the solution.