# ios sdk - checking true type of a newly created nsmanagedobject's property (with value of type nsnull)

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

i am creating various nsmanagedobjects from nsdictionaries and while i am iterating over the object's properties i assign the corresponding values from the dictionary.

currently i check the type like this:

```
if ([attributeValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
   ...
}
```

now the problem is that once the managed object is created, all (e.g. string) values do not respond to comparing classes. apparently they are not nsnull either. i miss everything but the nsnumbers.

```
[[attributeValue class] description]
```

this is empty for everything but the nsnumbers on the unset values.

is there a way to access the type of the property itself like it is defined in the class header, instead of using the (still unset) value?

Comment: oh, and i want to achieve this without custom setter methods like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425079/nsmanagedobject-how-to-get-the-type-of-the-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every NSManagedObject in a model has a corresponding [NSEntityDescription](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html).  You can use the entity description to get the list of [attributes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001173-BCIDDFGC) and [relationships](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001173-BCIHCHGF).  These will be [NSAttributeDescription](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSAttributeDescription_Class/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAttributeDescription)s or [NSRelationshipDescription](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSRelationshipDescription_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSRelationshipDescription)s which have in them the information you require.

Comment: thanks jeremy! i just figured this out a few minutes ago and it was exactly what i wanted. another case of rtfm... thank you for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is a late answer, but as I was search today for a good solution...
This is what I'm using now:

```
NSEntityDescription * myEntity = [object entity];
NSDictionary * attributes = [myEntity attributesByName];
if ([[[attributes objectForKey:key] attributeValueClassName] isEqualToString:@"NSDate"]) {
    // this type is NSDate
}
```

Hope this helps :)